# Using SSJS filter NotContains

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Has anyone have success of using SSJS filters to exclude data that contains a particular string?

I am trying to get a list of Marketing Cloud users that the AccountUser.Name doesn't contain the word 'user'.

Sadly,`notExistsInString` and `notContains` only for the DataFilter. I got the following error when I used it

> StatusError: "notExistsInString" is not a valid SimpleOperator for a
> retrieve Filter.

```js
var filterNotAppUser = {
    Property: "Name",
    SimpleOperator: "notExistsInString",
    Value: "user"
};

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ["ID", "Name", "Email","ActiveFlag"];
var myUsers = prox.retrieve("AccountUser", cols, filterNotAppUser);
Write("Status" + myUsers.Status);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to exclude installed packages (when you create an installed package, it creates a user). I would use the following code, as app users don't have an email address, but an email is required for other users (and `isNotNull` is not a valid operator for filtering objects, so we can't use that).

```js
var filterNotAppUser = {
    Property: "Email",
    SimpleOperator: "like",
    Value: "%@%"
};

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ["ID", "Name", "Email","ActiveFlag",];
var myUsers = prox.retrieve("AccountUser", cols, filterNotAppUser);
Write(Stringify(myUsers));
```

Comment: Hi Eliot. Thanks for your reply. Yes, my goal was to exclude the app users. I tried the filter you mentioned (Email LIKE '%@%' together with ActiveFlag as complex filter), it still returned a handful of "app users", which I think they were created by some sort of legacy process. I guessed I can add another filter to exclude these "app users" by user names and emails.